# How to capture Audio data in Java

Tags: java, audio, capture

I want to access the audio data that my microphone is recording with Java. How would I do that?

My goal is to save the audio data that is recorded and simultaneously play it to the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need any of the additional functionality in JMF, I would avoid it since development has ceased (last version is from 2004), it has compatibility issues with Java 6, has a very restricted functionality in 64-bit VMs and has to installed as a separate extension library.

Audio recording, playback and a few simple media formats are supported directly by JavaSound (javax.sound), which is part of the standard Java API.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Java Media Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/)

> The Java Media Framework API (JMF)
>   enables audio, video and other
>   time-based media to be added to
>   applications and applets built on Java
>   technology. This optional package,
>   which can capture, playback, stream,
>   and transcode multiple media formats,
>   extends the Java 2 Platform, Standard
>   Edition (J2SE) for multimedia
>   developers by providing a powerful
>   toolkit to develop scalable,
>   cross-platform technology.

It should have all you need.