# Capture and store the video using java media framework?

Tags: java, video-capture, jmf

I taked the snapshot but I can't record the video and store into hard disk. How to recording the video using JMF? If anyone know, then give the procedure..

Comment: You expected an answer within 13 minutes?  Give it some time.

Comment: Most of the question seems to refer to video rather than a still image, but you start off asking about a "snapshot"; are you looking for video help, or image help?

Comment: You should google it before asking. This is what I found http://72.5.124.102/thread.jspa?messageID=10696913

Comment: @Enrique, "being easily Google-able" doesn't necessarily mean a question isn't suitable for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pending an answer to my comment above...

Since you mentioned a "snapshot," you may be interested in JMF's [BufferToImage](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/2.1.1/apidocs/javax/media/util/BufferToImage.html); the API says

> This is a utility class to convert a video Buffer object to an AWT Image object that you can then render using AWT methods.

**NB**, from [an SO question about audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265574/how-to-capture-audio-data-in-java/2266021#2266021):

> If you don't need any of the additional functionality in JMF, I would avoid it since development has ceased (last version is from 2004), it has compatibility issues with Java 6, has a very restricted functionality in 64-bit VMs and has to installed as a separate extension library.

Comment: @Lord: Thanks.. But after that (2004), there is no updates and no sources for JMF.. What's the reason? Is there any concepts introduced instead of JMF?

Comment: @Venkats, I've never used JMF myself, but [Wikipedia has some suggestions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework#Criticism_and_alternatives).  Also, the project's [forums](http://forums.sun.com/forum.jspa?forumID=28) still seem lively in spite of the lack of development being done.